# Suggest some free tutorial for magento 2 associate developer certification please Didnt found anything on internet.Any help would be appreciated

Tags: magento2

i m planning to answer magento 2 associate developer exam, can anyone plz suggest me some content for the same.
All the cources which are given are paid ones also the exam fee is also not cheap, so wanted some reliable source, Please suggest some.

Answer (score 0):

Although some of the resources need updates due to latest Magento versions, most of the stuff still applies, check this out:

https://github.com/colinmurphy/magento-exam-notes

https://github.com/magento-notes/magento2-exam-notes (this one has more recent updates)

In the readme of the repos above you will find references to other resources as well.

Wish you best of luck!